docker-compose creates container but does not start apache container
I am using docker-compose to start two containers, one an apache container and the other a maria container.  The maria container starts but the apache container shows as created on the docker desktop dashboard but not started.  I tried stripping down the Dockerfile.apache script but it would never start up.  It seems as if it never gets to the EXPOSE and the last CMD lines.  How can I fix this issue?
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  app-mysql:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: app-mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: BLahBL$h123abc
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    volumes:
      - ../dbfiles:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "exit | mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 30
    networks:
      - app-net
  app-apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.apache
    container_name: app-apache
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ../app/:/var/www/html
      - ../../app-root:/root/app_main
    depends_on:
      app-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - app-net

networks:
  app-net:
    driver: bridge

Dockerfile.apache:
FROM ubuntu/apache2
COPY ["setup/php.ini", "/usr/local/etc/php/8.2/cli"]
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl \
    && apt-get install -y php php-mysql php-fpm php-mbstring default-mysql-client default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

CMD ["cd", "/root/app_main"]
CMD ["bash", "recreate.sh", "&"]
WORKDIR /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND

command to start the containers:
docker compose up


You can only have 1 CMD directive within a dockerfile, so presumably your recreate.sh isn't being executed like you suspect.  If you want your dockerfile to execute multiple things, you can encapsulate all commands into a single bash execution.

The issue is that I need the recreate.sh to run before I start apache but it depends on items in the volume that is created when docker-compose is run.

Also, I commented out the other CMD lines and it still seems to only create the image and the container but not start the container.  I see this line right after the execution or the WORKDIR line,  [app-apache] exporting to image.

This line might be the issue but I am not sure what the cause might be, dependency failed to start: container app-mysql is unhealthy

For some reasons, mysql is not found on the app-mysql container, so its healthcheck failed. As your app-apache container depends on the app-mysql with a condition: service_healthy, it cannot start.
You can either remove condition: service_healthy and just keep
depends_on: app-mysql. With that, you only need your app-mysql container running to start the apache container.
Or you can install mysql on the app-mysql container with a Dockerfile :
Dockerfile.mariadb
FROM mariadb:latest 
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client

and edit your docker-compose :
app-mysql:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.mariadb
container_name: app-mysql

